# "Internet not availabe" Error on Samsung Galaxy A3 (2016)

Tags: wi-fi, samsung, internet

I have a Samsung Galaxy A3 (2016) model.

My mobile Wi-Fi keeps connecting and disconnecting; showing that the internet isn't available, this usually happens when my roommate connects to the same Wi-Fi network, as he starts using Wi-Fi, my mobile starts disconnecting, he has a Samsung Galaxy A7(2016) model.

When he resets the mobile Wi-Fi setting, my wifi works normally for some days then agin this problem starts.

So, my **question** is described above, and your solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If the same thing doesn't occur on public networks (i.e. School or coffee shop networks) then I would imagine it's a problem with your router.